# Navigation bar with prompt - replace with image

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

How can I make replace a "navigation bar with prompt" with a same size image?
I have seen this in other apps. All I can do is replace the navigation bar alone with no prompt. I want the size with the prompt so that I can put a heighty logo.

Thanks for any resource.

Comment: Are you want custom navigation bar?

Comment: a prompt is the extension of the navigation bar..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i hope this works for u.

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"";
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR IMAGE NAME"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 0, 10, 10); //change height and width accordingly
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
```

happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much!..
self.navigationItem.prompt = @""; is awesome!!

Comment: @anshuk, now I have a problem, how can I remove the image in the child view? and it's animating to the default size of 44..

Comment: @vishiphone http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/prompt this will help u.

Comment: @zeekerg: make the UIImageView object as member variable and remove the added subview from the navigation bar in viewWillDisappear:animated:

Comment: @AnshukGarg, ok thanks got it. but it still animates to the height of my image when I tapped back button.