# Add UIView when keyboard is shown without being dimmed out

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield

This question is a bit difficult to explain.  I have a textfield on top (where the navigation bar is usually is) and when I start editing text, the keyboard shows and auto dims the background.  I want to add another UIView below the textfield but have that visible and not dimmed out.

Perfect image that describes what I want is this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Art/keyboard_size.jpg

[image]
I want to implement something similar like that google search bar underneath the search url bar.  Notice how that is not dimmed out?  How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use navigation bar prompt for this. Look at the answer here [Navigation bar with prompt - replace with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479475/navigation-bar-with-prompt-replace-with-image)

Answer (score 0):

The Google search bar sits above the overlay view (the part that is dimmed). It is relatively easy to build the navigation bar, the textview, the view that you are wanting, and the webview beneath, respectively. If you want the dimmed look for the webview portion, then that too is relatively easy to implement, but I am not certain that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to build the Google search bar that sits above the overlay view.  How would I go about in implementing that?

If I do a [self addSubview] of the textfield, that gets dimmed out 
which I do not want.

Basically, I want to add things ABOVE the dimmed part.