# Add UIView on top of dimmed background

Tags: ios, uiview

The image
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Art/keyboard_size.jpg
[image]
If you look at the first image, the google search bar is above the dimmed background.  How would I go about achieving this?  If I do a [self.view addSubview] method it appears below the dimmed background.

One way I found to achieve this is [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:scanView].  I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution out there?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you repeating your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603784/add-uiview-when-keyboard-is-shown-without-being-dimmed-out

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bringSubviewToFront:` to arrange the views properly.

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];
```

[UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) has a few other methods that could also be useful for arranging views:

- sendSubviewToBack:
- insertSubview:atIndex:
- insertSubview:aboveSubview:
- insertSubview:belowSubview:
- exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:

Comment: I am adding the subview on the UITextField Delegate method 'textFieldShouldBeginEditing'.  I want the view to show right when the user clicks on the UITextField.  And that is when the keyboard shows and the background dims. Even with [self.view bringSubviewToFront], it is still underneath the background.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `bringSubviewToFront` should work. Can you add the code you have to your question?